# PHP strings concatenation

Tags: php

My code cycles through a CSV file, converting it to XML:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < $arraySize; $i++) {
    $n = 0;
    if (substr($csv[$i][0], 0, 1) == $let) {
        $surName = $dom->createElement('name');
        $name = $csv[$i][0];
        $nameText = $dom->createTextNode($name);
        $surName->appendChild($nameText);

        $text = str_replace(chr(94), ",", $csv[$i][4]);
        $n = $i + 1;
        $next = $csv[$n][0];

        while ($next == 'NULL') {
            $repl = str_replace(chr(94), ",",  $csv[$n][4]);
            $text = $repl;

            $n++;
            $next = $csv[$n][0];
        }
        $bio = $dom->createElement('bio');
        $bioText = $dom->createTextNode($text);
        $bio->appendChild($bioText);
        $person = $dom->createElement('person');
        $person->appendChild($surName);
        $person->appendChild($bio);
        $people->appendChild($person);
    }
}
$xmlString = $dom->saveXML();
echo $xmlString; 
?>
```

The problem is the `$text = $repl;`  Typing `$text .= $repl;` brings:

```
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty.
```

but omitting the `.` just gives the last line of text.
the backup code works:
        public function test($let){
        $csv = $this->readCSV("data\AlphaIndex1M.csv");
        $arraySize=sizeof($csv);
        $let = strtoupper($let);
        //echo '';
        for($i=1; $i
                echo $csv[$i][0];// .'
                echo ', -->'.$csv[$i][4];
                $n = $i+1;
                $next = $csv[$n][0];
                //if($next == 'NULL'){  }
                while($next == 'NULL'){
                    echo $csv[$n][4]. " ";
                    $n++;
                    $next=$csv[$n][0];
                }
                //echo ''
                echo '';
            }
        }
        //echo ''
    }

Comment: Try to initialize $text first like: `$text = ""` (Not in the loop)

Comment: looks like something else is going on and the code sample is not complete. shouldn't it be `while ($next != NULL) {}` or better `!is_null($next)`? If you have a jagged CSV, it looks like there could be errors due to the hard coding (like for index `[4]`). Also: are you sure the csv is valid for parsing, that data is not presented here.

Comment: I thought of this, so I went to excel and replaced blank cells with "Null", and ',' with '^'; ex: ADAMS #221,ADAMS #221,Somersetshire^ England,1640,John ADAMS b/d Somersetshire Eng; m. Agnes ___. [per Savage:  John^ a tailor^ was in Newbury^ MA^ by 1640.]  
NULL,SQUIRE,Braintree,,Henry ADAMS b. Somerset^ Eng. abt 1583; orig. proprietor of Braintree;  m. Eng.^ 1609^ Edith SQUIRE; d. Braintree 1646.  Ancestor of Pres. John Adams.
NULL,,Braintree^ Medfield,,Edward ADAMS of Medfield^ b. Kingweston/Somerset^ Eng. 1629; m. 1652 in MA^ Lydia PENNIMAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize your `$text` before you can append stuff!

So write this before you use it:

```
$test = "";
```

(before the `while` loop or even before the `for` loop if you want all to be appended)

Comment: Nope, get This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: My stupid, stupid mistake for not initializing the $text variable.  Please vote for my question so that my questioning ban can be lifted, and my education in programming can continue.

Comment: @Lynn I did this already, but you don't ask people to vote up the vote up if they want!

Comment: Somebody on this site thinks that an algorithm can decide when a person doesn't deserve to ask questions.  Just trying to make their AI happy.